# SAS ODBC License Error

Tags: sas, odbc

I'm trying to connect to a Postgresql database using SAS ODBC. I'm getting the message:

```
ERROR: The product with which the engine ODBC is associated is either not licensed for your 
       system or the product license has expired.
```

I thought SAS ODBC was default installed with SAS Base? Or do I need SAS/Access for it to work? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You require:

```
---SAS/ACCESS Interface to ODBC
```

It's not part of Base SAS.

To find out what modules you have licensed, you can run: `proc setinit;run;`

Comment: Thanks for the help!